# How to add page templates to Wagtail after installing into an existing Django application

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to extend an already existing Django App. The app is functioning fine as is, but I would like to add blog functionality.

I've installed Wagtail, using the guidelines here (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html)  To check wagtail is installed, I have navigated to here: 
http://myurl/cms

And the wagtail admin panel is displayed. When I navigate to http://myurl/admin I get the default admin control panel for my Django app, so far so good.

Now I am trying to build the blog.

I found this tutorial: 
http://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2015/06/22/developing-wagtail/ 
which suggests the following as a first step: -

> First, we’ll create our generic page class as home page class is
>   already created by default when we started Wagtail project.

It then displays this code:

```
# core/models.py

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.wagtailsearch import index

# We’re deriving our GenericPage from Page class, so that our GenericPage also has Page’s field, e.g. title
class GenericPage(Page):
    # Let’s create our custom field, named body which is a rich text
    body = RichTextField()

    # Index the body field, so that it will be searchable
    search_fields = Page.search_fields + (index.SearchField(‘body'),) # To show our body field in admin panel, we have to wrap it with FieldPanel and add it to Page’s field panel content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel('body', classname=‘full’)]
```

I could not find which file I was meant to add this into. I searched the system using grep, and found a number of files that had the text string:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
```

I decided the most likely candidate was in the directory:

```
env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/project_template
```

Within my original app directory. I added the code above to the models.py file residing in the above directory. I then ran

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

But it said no migrations were found. The next step in the tutorial posted above suggests you should now see three different page types available to create in the control panel, but I can not find the option to create any pages.

1. Can you tell me if I edited the correct file above, or if I should have edited a different file, and also
2. Why I am not seeing any option to add a new page in the wagtail control panel?

I have consulted with the documentation here (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html) and tried following the 'extend the homepage model' section, but couldn't figure out where the home/models.py file is as there is no folder called home in my Django app.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [final section of the "integrating into Django" docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html#start-developing) says:

> You’re now ready to add a new app to your Django project (via `./manage.py startapp` - remember to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS`) and set up page models

Running `./manage.py startapp blog` will add a `blog` app to your project, including an empty `models.py` - this is where you add your page definitions. (The Wagtail docs don't go into detail on this, because it's just following the standard Django workflow, which is hopefully familiar to anyone with an existing Django project to integrate with...)

Tutorials that use `wagtail start my_project` as a starting point will omit this step, because the starter project comes with a pre-made `models.py` with a HomePage model. The `site-packages/wagtail/project_template` directory you found is actually the 'master' copy of the starter project, which gets cloned at the point that you run `wagtail start my_project`. Since this isn't hooked up to your current project, changing it had no effect.

Comment: Thanks @gasman I've created the blog app now, and added it to installed apps in the settings.py of my main project, I edited the models.py of the new app, to match the sample models.py , under the extend the home page model, here (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html) i've ran 'manage.py makemigrations' and 'manage.py migrate' and they completed. I'm just struggling to figure out what I do next to see any difference in the wagtail control panel.

Comment: If you've set everything up correctly, you should see your defined page types when you go to Explorer -> Homepage -> Add child page.

Comment: How does the wagtail admin panel know that I updated the models.py in my new blog app? I'm not quite understanding the link between the two